Not able to use drbd over lustre zfs
I am running the below command to format the nvme drive to lustre with backfstype as zfs
mkfs.lustre --mdt --reformat --mgsnode=mgsmaster@tcp --backfstype=zfs --fsname=lustre mdtpool/mdt --index=0 /dev/nvme1n1

After formatting the drive
I am trying to setup drbd using the below resource config
resource "r0" {
protocol C; //Updated
device /dev/drbd0; //Updated
disk /dev/nvme1n1;
meta-disk internal;
options {
auto-promote no;
}
on "hostname1" {
node-id 0;
}
on "hostname2" {
node-id 1;
}
connection {
host "hostname1" address 10.40.40.1:7789;
host "hostname2" address 10.40.40.2:7789;
}
}

after this I run the below command to initialize drbd
drbdadm create-md r0

open(/dev/nvme1n1) failed: Device or resource busy
...

I found this post on the drbd website where it's mentioned that ZFS doesn't hold the device open in the kernel the same way other filesystems or processes in Linux do
DRBD Reference website for zfs
Need some help here.
I tried first setting up drbd on the drive and then formatting with mkfs.lustre but then it's the same mkfs.lustre wants drbd service to be down, and only after that it can format
update: The issue has been resolved
The steps for replication are as follows:
drbdadm create-md r0
drbdadm up r0
drbdadm primary r0 --force
mkfs.lustre --mdt --reformat --mgsnode=mgsmaster@tcp --backfstype=zfs --fsname=lustre mdtpool/mdt --index=0 /dev/drbd0
mount -t mdtpool/mdt /mnt/MDT

If we want to remount after reboot
drbdadm up r0
drbdadm primary r0 --force
zpool import -o cachefile=none mdtpool
mount -t mdtpool/mdt /mnt/MDT


You cannot have both trying to use the /dev/nvme1n1 device directly. You will have to layer them.
Assuming that you want to use DRBD to replicate the lustre filesystem, then you will want to setup DRBD first and then place the lustre filesystem atop the DRBD device. Essentially you configure DRBD as you have in the example above. Then you will promote DRBD to primary with drbdadm primary r0, at this point you will have an accessible /dev/drbd0 device. Then run the mkfs.lustre targeting the DRBD device to create the ZFS and lustre filesystem atop the DRBD. For example:
mkfs.lustre --mdt --reformat --mgsnode=mgsmaster@tcp --backfstype=zfs --fsname=lustre mdtpool/mdt --index=0 /dev/drbd0

This way you will have things layered like so: Lustre -> ZFS -> DRBD -> Physical disk.

I did do this and it worked, but now after I reboot the system and run  drbdadm up r0 and then mount the lustre MDT, it throws an error that the file system has not been formatted using mkfs.lustre. Any reason why this is not persistent. Thanks

update - issue resolved thanks !
